# Using Microsoft Translator Versus using Local translation file for have 2 languages (English & Arabic ) Inside our canvas apps

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

We want to build 8 Canvas Power Apps >> and we need to have 2 Languages; English + Arabic.

now i have not implemented such thing before. but seems we have 2 approaches to follow:-

1. Using MS translator
2. Using Local translation excel sheet

so can i know the advantages and disadvantageous of each approach?

Thanks

Comment: can you describe the first approach? Who suggested it to you?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-yCb70FLwY mainly the first 7 minutes

Comment: 1) sending an API call to translate every label on the screen sounds like an overkill. Why not translate everything once, in Excel? 2) I don't think MS translator can compete with a human yet. Native speakers will probably see lots of funny out-of-place terms. In Excel you have a chance to correct these

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov totally agree with you